# cucumber-JVM report after every scenario

Tags: cucumber-jvm

We have test automation scripts in Cucumber-JVM. At the moment it takes about 2 hours to execute our scripts and we are using json formatter for report. We get report after execution.

Is there a way to publish cucumber.json report after every scenario using json formatters? I should be able to see the report during the execution. I dont have to wait until all the scripts are completed.

Answer (score 0):

More detail (e.g. is runtime Jenkins? Eclipse on linux desktop? Are you using log4j ?) would have been helpful.  That being said, in the After [hook](http://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/groovy/Hooks.html) you can write the scenario status to a file that you can then [tail](http://stackify.com/11-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/).

```
@After
public void afterScenarioExecution(Scenario scenario) {
  log = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class);
  log.info("Scenario: '" + scenario.getName() + "' has status " + scenario.getStatus());
  }
}
```

Your log4j.properties file could look like this:

```
# root level configurations
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console,file

# configuration for console outputs
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# configuration for file output (into a file named messages.log)
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=messages.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# threshold for file output
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=INFO
```

Of course if you have a console then no need to tail.